# Xiaomi 11 Ultra - rear display for vlogging

Tags: screen, camera, xiaomi

How I can see myself during video recording on Xiaomi 11 Ultra rear display ?

Is there any app which supports it or I have to wait until Xiaomi implements it.

I have Chinesse ROM. Ready to do anything to get it. Thank you!